# Scrollview height

Tags: android, scrollview

I have layout which contains a header, content in the scrollview and a footer.  The position of the header and footer should be fixed, but when I start the app, the footer isn't visible, I can only scroll to bottom of the content and that's it.  How can I make it so that I can still scroll down to bottom of the content, but that my footer is allways visible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#2E2E2E"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#CC0000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
         <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/internet_group_chat" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NG Online"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>


    </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:background="#990000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mBtnNaslovnica"
            style="@style/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Naslovnica" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mBtnVjesti"
            style="@style/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Vjesti" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mBtnVideo"
            style="@style/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Video" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mBtnFoto"
            style="@style/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2.33"
            android:text="Fotogalerija" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cur_news_title"
                        android:layout_width="300dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Large Text"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />  
                </LinearLayout>
                <FrameLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/cur_news_img"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/rihanna" />
                    <LinearLayout
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:background="#B3000000"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <LinearLayout
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp" >                    
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/cur_news_atuhor"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:text="Small Text"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/cur_news_time"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:text="Small Text"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="#CC0000"
                            android:layout_marginTop="7dp" />
                        <LinearLayout
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <LinearLayout
                                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_height="1dp"
                                android:background="#CC0000" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#F5F5F5">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Više o"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                <LinearLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="#333333" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=" dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcodolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcodolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcodolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcodolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcodolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcodolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcodolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco "
                    android:textColor="#666666"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView> 
            <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#CC0000" />
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#4D000000"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:background="#CC0000"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="AKTUALNO"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>
            <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/scroller"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="09:50 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit | 09:59 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit | 10:10 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit | 10:20 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit | 10:34 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `layout_weight` for the ScrollView so that it does not take all the remaining space:

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
```

Answer (score -1):

add `android:layout_weight` to the `ScrollView`